# How dynamically adds third-party dependencies to Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm submitting a `flink job jar` and want to use a thin jar. How to add third-party jar when submitting a Flink job.

I tried to use flink run command with `-C --classpath`, but it didn't work.

This is my command.

```
bin/flink run -c compute.service.job.CPUAvgCalculateJob -C /home/mylib/*.jar -d /tmp/flink-web-e42f3efd-b063-4ef4-987c-c5f6a60ebd17/flink-web-upload/41b0aa60-c3ea-485d-96fe-7b33b3cd581f_flink-example-1.0.jar
```

I expect to run the job with classpath

Comment: Well to do that You would need to have the libraries on Your flink cluster that You want to run Your job on.